# Saving out multiple files in Windows Store

Tags: c#, io, windows-store-apps

I have a windows store app that uses an internal file library hosted in localstorage. Is there anyway to export these en masse without needing to make the user choose a location / file name for each file?

I know I can zip them up and export the zip, but I was hoping to allow the user to choose a folder and then save a series of text files into that folder. Is this possible?

I'm not looking for someone to write my code for me, just point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get the files in a List (from LocalStorage)
- run a foreach loop (for the `List<Files>`)
- let user choose the location once (in phone memory or m/m card)
- and then simply copy all files in the same location one by one through the foreach loop (because you have the `StorageFolder`, you can use `StorageFile`'s `CopyAsync` method)

I've done this in my WP store App (kind of File Explorer).

Hope this helps..!